# Middle Mouse Button does not work in XFCE / Arch Linux

Tags: linux, mouse, arch-linux, xfce

I have the XFCE desktop manager installed on my Arch Linux system. With E17 (Enlightenment desktop manager) I had no problems with my mouse: all buttons worked correctly out of the box. But in XFCE my middle mouse button does not fire an event at all (no output with `xev`).

Evdev seems to identify my mouse correctly (Razer Deathadder) because it echoes its name in the xorg logs. I have no idea what could cause this and how to debug the problem.

I start both E17 and XFCE with `startx`. Here is my `~/.xinitrc`:

```
exec startxfce4 --with-ck-launch
#exec enlightenment-start
```

Comment: How do you start xorg and XFCE? Does the problem occur if you first use `xinit`, then `startxfce4`? If so, at what point does it happen? What if you start XFCE from inside E? Are the same events mapped to the same buttons otherwise in E and XFCE?

Comment: I added some information to the question. Is it even possible to start XFCE from inside E? I'll try `xinit` later.

Answer (score 1):

See the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Razer) page for Razer input devices.

The `razercfg` site link there is out of date, so download it from the [developer site](http://bues.ch/cms/hacking/razercfg.html). Your device appears to be fully supported.

The `razercfg` and `razercfg-git` AUR links that the wiki mentions are also currently out of date, so don't waste your time with those until the packagers update them.

Comment: Nice idea, but sadly i can't get it to run. Neither the official version, nor the AUR packages work after installing them: `> razercfg
  File "/usr/local/bin/razercfg", line 143
    except (ValueError), e:
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: That sounds like you have a python version mismatch. Do you have python2 installed? What did you do to get the AUR packages to install? Maybe some needed dependency isn't being enforced in the PKGBUILD.

Comment: yes i have python2 installed

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is HW related (did you try the mouse on another PC?), here is what worked for me.

I had the same problem with a Logitech G602 mouse. The issue was with hardware button. I opened the mouse (mine has screws hidden behind plastic pads) and put some WD40 on the button just below the wheel. I let it dry a bit, move and used the button several times and added again some WD40 and repeated the click and shake of the button. I reassembled the mouse and voila! the middle click button is working again.